# Lightning Process Builder - Remove extra actions

Tags: process-builder, lightning

I am trying to create a process via Lightning process builder.

Basically it checks whether the opportunity belongs to a particular record type and if it is then sets the owner as a specific user.

By default it appears and I have not added it to the above process.

[image]

Can someone tell me how am I supposed to remove the second diamond box (and the associated schedule boxes) from the above the flow chart ?.

I am not able to drag and drop and as such I am stuck and unable to proceed further.

Comment: It is there to allow you to add an additional logic check. Other than being an empty spot on the page it is not doing anything. At this point you just have to "deal with it" as it is purely aesthetics...and cannot currently be removed

Comment: Tx mate... You can put this as answer

Comment: done.................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is there to allow you to add an additional logic check. Other than being an empty spot on the page it is not doing anything. At this point you just have to "deal with it" as it is purely aesthetics...and cannot currently be removed

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking this because you cant activate this Process Builder.  It is not the extra criteria that is the issue.  As the others have said, this is aesthetic and should be ignored.

The reason you cant activate it is you have no action if the first criteria is TRUE.